# why Bilinear interpoation generates exact original image on expanding and shrinking by same factor

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-scaling, zooming, linear-interpolation

So I have implemented the bi-linear interpolation as in wiki,and other sources where they use the fraction of distance from the neighboring pixels to compute their contributions. 
My two issues are:

1. my results don't tally with the matlab implementation of resize that uses bi-linear interpolation
2. I expand the original image I_org to generate I_expanded with scale s,
   the I expand I_expanded with scale 1/s to generate I_shrunk.
   The issue is I_org and I_shrunk are always invariably the exact same, I was expecting at least some pixels to differ.

[link to source](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwiu9vj1_MjHAhVXA44KHVejDiE&url=http%3A%2F%2Farchive.org%2Fdownload%2FLectures_on_Image_Processing%2FEECE253_12_Resampling.pdf&ei=49veVe74JteGuATXxrqIAg&usg=AFQjCNFpl49nb6tD-Br8DFofDGe0W2x2qA&sig2=hwoE6ENjXIRtlhqrWFCjew)

[image: original]

[image: expanded]

[image: shrunk]

now original image and shrunk image are always same, I was expecting that due to the expanding and shrinking the shrunk image will slightly different from original.

My implementation in based on slide 96 ,
[image: slide 96]

Comment: Please add a [mcve] of the cod, the obtained results and the desired results here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you  Increase and decrease the resolution in powers of 2 (x2 x4 x8 ...) then, most likely you will get the same image. This is because you are effectively doing pyramidal-like scaling (note that the [real pyramidal scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_(image_processing)) has a blurring step before re-sampling)

Try, instead of doing x4 scaling (as in the posted images), to perform a 3.5 scale (or any other non power of two scale). Then Most likely you'll get different results.

Comment: you are spot on, could you direct me to some link, where I can understand this in more details?